# TFLearn Alexnet customized to a certain number of classes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the [Alexnet](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/91e617c3f4ad94db5ea52fe09b7338035c517d28/examples/images/alexnet.py) example given in TFLearn to train on my own dataset of images, which is the [GroZi-120 database](http://grozi.calit2.net/grozi.html), so I need to change it slightly to output for 120 classes.

I'm not very familiar with convnets and deep learning in general, so I'm not sure how to modify the code to output properly for a score corresponding to the 120 classes.

I tried changing the softmax line to:

`network = fully_connected(network, 120, activation='softmax')`

but this gives me the error

`ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 17) for Tensor u'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 120)'`

Could someone clarify this/help me figure out how to proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1000, validation_set=0.1, shuffle=True,
      show_metric=True, batch_size=64, snapshot_step=200,
      snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='alexnet_oxflowers17')
```

You seem to still have the previous `Y` of shape `[batch_size, 17]` fed into the network.

You need to replace `X` and `Y` with your own.

Comment: How would that work? I've modified the input file that loads the data to work with my own directory of images as follows:
```
    X, Y = build_image_dataset_from_dir('../train_photos/',
                                        resize=resize_pics,
                                        filetypes=['.png'],
                                        convert_gray=False,
                                        shuffle_data=shuffle,
                                        categorical_Y=one_hot)

    return X, Y
```
where my directory of images is separated into subdirectories for each class.

Comment: And what do `X.shape` and `Y.shape` return?

Comment: I get (11194, 224, 224, 3) and (11194, 120) for X and Y, respectively.

Comment: Can you print `Y.shape` just before the line `model.fit(X, Y)` and see if you still get the same error?

Comment: I think I changed one_hot to be false before this for some reason, but I changed it to be true and now it works. Thank you!